# jQuery in Woo-box Facebook iframe

Tags: jquery, facebook, iframe

I created a "Facebook tab" in my page with Woo-box, that is an iframe loaded in a Facebook page.

It works fine. Now I want to insert some jQuery scripts, but all my efforts were vain.

Is it not possible at all with Woobox?

This example does not work (this is the entire code of the tab as I can insert it in the GUI of Woobox).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
      $("#a_div").hide();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="a_div">
      This is some HTML content
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Screenshots:

Code: http://gyazo.com/34f96fcede569a4bcbd9bda083a5d06c

Render: http://gyazo.com/89874f31bcd1f959e26df9d6de93706e

Comment: Experiencing same issues, found out something yet?

Comment: Sadly, no. I quit Woobox, finally.

Comment: I got it working, anyone interested let me know.

Comment: Yeah, share please :-)

Comment: :) require alle the js files you need like so: ```<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"> </script>``` and make sure that the server for the requested .js supports ssl so that it might be reacheable at ```https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js``` for example. For more info on the reasons behind that refer to this: https://blog.mozilla.org/tanvi/2013/04/10/mixed-content-blocking-enabled-in-firefox-23/